# How to make a menuitem programmatically navigation in jsf 2.0 with primefaces 3.5

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

In one application here we are doing this before with richfaces like this:

```
  HtmlMenuItem menu = (HtmlMenuItem) context.getApplication().createComponent(HtmlMenuItem.COMPONENT_TYPE);  
                    menu.setValue(FacesUtils.bundle(item.getChavelocale()));   
                  //  menu.setSubmitMode("ajax");
                    menu.getAttributes().put("myParam", item.getNavegacao());
                    MethodExpression action = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(context.getELContext(), item.getNavegacao(), null, new Class<?>[0]);
                    menu.setActionExpression(action);
                    menu.setImmediate(false);
                    pai.getChildren().add(menu);
```

After migrating to primefaces we try this, but no action is executed:

```
  MenuItem menu = new MenuItem();  
                    menu.setValue(FacesUtils.bundle(item.getChavelocale()));   
                  //  menu.setSubmitMode("ajax");
                    menu.getAttributes().put("myParam", item.getNavegacao());
                    MethodExpression action = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(context.getELContext(), item.getNavegacao(), null, new Class<?>[0]);
                    menu.setActionExpression(action);
                    menu.setImmediate(true);
                    pai.getChildren().add(menu);
```

there is something wrong or this is not the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DefaultMenuModel`, `DefaultSubMenu`, and `DefaultMenuItem` objects.